# Missing columns in database, but only when testing

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit

I have a test which is failing due to a missing column in the database. The weird thing is the column is actually present.

Below is a little test I have run to prove that the column exists.

Controller

```
public function index()
{
    if (Schema::hasColumn('occurrences', 'occurrenceable_type')) {
        echo 'yes I have the bloody column';
    } else {
        echo 'no column for me!';
    }
}
```

returns >> 'yes I have the bloody column';

Test

```
public function an_admin_can_create_a_new_occurrence()
{
    if (Schema::hasColumn('occurrences', 'occurrenceable_type')) {
        echo 'yes I have the bloody column';
    } else {
        echo 'no column for me!';
    }
}
```

returns >> 'no column for me'

The differences between the test and controller are

Controller: database is a MySQL database connection

Testing: database is a MySQLite database running in memory.

the tests implement `use RefreshDatabase;` and if a run a `artisan migrate:refresh` on the MySQL database the column is present.

This is the migration used to build the that table

````

```
Schema::create('occurrences', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('occurrenceable_id');
        $table->integer('occurrenceable_type');
        $table->integer('occurrence_status_id');
        $table->text('days');
        $table->string('tutor')->nullable();
        $table->integer('location_id')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('start_date')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('end_date')->nullable();
        $table->text('additional_info')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->integer('created_by');
        $table->integer('updated_by');
        $table->integer('deleted_by');
    });
```

````

Why would there be differences between them? How can I solve it?

Comment: Can you post your migrations?

Comment: Hi @ThomasEdwards i've updated the question to include the migration for that table

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be an issue with the SQLite database if the tests are run on a MySQL database the issue doesn't appear and tests run successfully.